# Why doesn't the simplest example work (VHDL, Quartus)?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

Here is my VHDL code:

```vhdl
entity test is
    port (
        x1, x2 : in bit;
        f     : out bit
    ); 
end test;

architecture behavior of test is
begin
    f <= x1 and x2;
end behavior;
```

In Quartus (v. 18.1) I go to File->New->University Program VWF. In Simulation Waveform editor, I go to edit->insert->insert node or bus->node finder, push 'list' and select all nodes (in this case x1, x2, and f). Then I go to Simulation->Run functional simulation and get the error:

```
# ** Fatal: (vsim-3807) Types do not match between component and entity for port "f".
```

Do I need to change the type of port "f" in the component somewhere on Quartus, or what?

Comment: The error is not in the code shown, but in the testbench or upper level of the design. The component you have written is not using the type `bit` in the component declaration.

Comment: @Tricky, how can I change component declaration? I have only 2 files. The first file whith code above and the second is .vwf file. In .vwf file port 'f' has binary radix.

Comment: This a tool usage problem and not a VHDL issue. The Modelsim vsim error is the result of depending on an unsophisticated tool generating a testbench (in a .vho or .vht file) from your waveform description in Quartus likely expecting you to be be using std_logic based port signals. There are several options. Write your testbench yourself, switch to using std_logic or write a translation layer converting between type bit and type std_logic. You might also explore the limitations of the waveform interfacing software by reading documentation and/or following a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to solve this problem - use std_logic instead of bit. Here is working code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity test is
port (x1, x2: in std_logic;
        f: out std_logic); 
end test;

architecture behavior of test is
begin
f <= x1 and x2;
end behavior;
```